# Face++APIの処理をフォルダ内の画像すべてに行えるようにしたい

Tags: python, 機械学習, 画像

Face++のdetectAPIを使ってフォルダ内の画像すべてに処理を行い、その結果を1つのcsvファイルに保存するプログラムを完成させたいです。

公式ドキュメントでは画像一枚だけに処理を行うコードが書かれているのですがそれを改変して書こうとしています。

機械学習用の画像データセットを作ろうと思い、
①画像をスクレイピングにて一括取得。
②取得した画像をカスケードファイルにて顔部分だけにリサイズ

まで行いました。

```
# coding: utf-8
import os
import sys
import csv
import pandas as pd
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))))
import requests
from config import API_KEY, API_SECRET, DETECT_PATH ,ANALYZE_PATH
from example.common import get_input_file_path

return_landmark = 0
return_attributes = None
#calculate_all = 0
face_rectangle = ''
beauty_score_min = 0
beauty_score_max = 100

def call_api():
 data = {
     'api_key': API_KEY,
     'api_secret': API_SECRET,
     'return_landmark': 1,
     'return_attributes': 'gender,age,emotion'
     #'calculate_all': calculate_all,
     #'beauty_score_min': beauty_score_min,
     #'beauty_score_max': beauty_score_max
 }

 data_dir_path = u"E:/facepp-python-demo-master/facepp-python-demo-master/example/detect/images/images01/"
 file_list = os.listdir(r'E:/facepp-python-demo-master/facepp-python-demo-master/example/detect/images/images01')



#この内部の処理がうまくいっていない
##################################################   
 if face_rectangle:
     data.update({'face_rectangle': face_rectangle})
     print(1)
     for f in file_list:
         root, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
         print(2)
         if ext == u'.png' or u'.jpeg' or u'.jpg':
             abs_name = data_dir_path + '/' + f
             image = cv.imread(abs_name)
             print(3)
         #以下各画像に対する処理を記載する
             files = {
                'image_file': open(image, 'rb').read()
             }
             resp = requests.post(DETECT_PATH, data=data, files=files).json()

             with open('emotion.csv','w') as csv_file:
                 writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
                 for key, value in resp.items():
                     writer.writerows(resp)

             (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=resp,orient='index').to_csv('emotion_csv',header=False))
             print(4)
             osp = resp['faces']
             df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(osp)
             print(df)
             df.to_csv('emotion2_csv')
 #input_file = get_input_file_path(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'input')
         if not f:
             print('请将input.png/input.jpg文件放在detect目录下')
             return

 #(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=osp, orient='index').to_csv('emotion2_csv', header=False))
 #print(resp['faces'])
################################################







if __name__ == "__main__":
 call_api()
```

各箇所にプリント文を挟んでみたところ、どこがうまくいっていないのかは理解できたのですが、具体的にどうすればうまく処理が進むのかがわからず投稿させていただきました。

Comment: 処理結果に影響があるのかどうかは不明ですが、`ext == u'.png' or u'.jpeg' or u'.jpg'` は `(ext == u'.png') or (u'.jpeg') or (u'.jpg')` という評価が為されますので、`ext` の値に関わらず常に `True` になります。`ext in ('.png', '.jpeg', '.jpg')` とするのが適切かと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます